# prevent browser from showing popup window warning in gwt

Tags: java, gwt

In GWT when I click on a button to open  popup window where URL is initially set to `Window.open(URL,"_blank","")`, my browser (Firefox) opens that window without asking to allow popup windows. But when I get the URL from an RPC call in GWT/fetch URL from the database and use `Window.open(URL,"_blank","")`, my browser asks to allow popup windows.

How do I prevent the browser showing this warning, without changing browser's property? If I set global variable to set URL in on button's `onSubmit()` method then it takes double click to open.

Answer (score 1):

you hava use:

```
Window.open(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+ "ServletFile"+ String uri of file, "parameter name", "");
```

You may try it works fine.

Comment: I want to call payment gateway direct link with some parameters, don't want to use separate servlet for user command, I improved my code using FormPanel passing hidden parameters instead of passing parameters with url, but if I don't add exception in popup blocker of Firefox I get error like com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (NS_ERROR_FAILURE): Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMHTMLFormElement.submit] at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)